# Yii2 setFlash Правильный вывод сообщения

Tags: php, yii2

Вообщем у меня есть проект на yii2, я там в админке делаю редактирование товара и всё работает, после я записываю, что человеку нужно показать сообщение т.е.:

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Товар $model->title сохранен");
```

Проблема в том, что по некоторым причинам, мне приходится после этого делать для страницы refresh, что бы все сохраненные данные показались правильно, но тогда сообщение уже не показывается. Так, вот как мне сделать, чтобы оно именно после перезагрузки показалось??

```
Вывод сообщения:

<?php if (Yii::$app->session->getFlash('message')): ?>
    <div class="flash">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4> <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('message') ?></h4>
        </div>
     </div>
 <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сохранять данные не в session, а в кэше с временем жизни.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/caching-data

```
Yii::$app->cache->set('product_saved', "Товар $model->title сохранен", 60);
...
<?php if (Yii::$app->cache->get('product_saved')): ?>
```